# Windows Store App QUnit Testing

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, qunit

Has anyone used QUnit to test Windows Store App?  Any recommendations on how to run testing smoothly?  I seem to be having issues stubbing methods that cite some of the internal Windows. references.  Is there a way to run QUnit while the metro app is actually running, instead of writing tests in a standalone fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project started recently that helps you use QUnit in Metro apps

[QUnit-Metro](http://qunitmetro.github.com/QUnitMetro/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two QunitMetro libraries available
Codeplex http://qunitmetro.github.com/QUnitMetro/
MSDN Code Gallery http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9a49206d-8b60-4324-a23f-eb01264ece3d

I recommend the CodePlex version as I have not tried the MSDN one.